# Is There a Name for the Lines of an Arrowhead?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, image-identification

Given an arrow head symbol, formed by two lines, is there a name for ***each*** of  these lines, individually? 
If not, perhaps a term that could be used to clearly convey that idea? 
For example: "arrowhead edge"?

[image]

If I had to choose among flavors,
I would prefer a term that would be understood in American English.

**Note:**
I'm getting answers and comments describing an arrow head. 
I don't want that. 
I want to know the name of a line that *makes up* half of an arrow head.

Comment: You want its definition in British English or American English?

Comment: @user5768790 American would be nice... though are the different?

Comment: We say *side of a square*. There is no word that makes a side distinctly belong to a square. I would say *edge of an arrow*.

Comment: I’d be inclined to use ‘‘leg’’, but I don’t know whether I’ve ever heard that usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though not typically used in relation to symbology, in hunting this would commonly be referred to as a "[barb](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/barb)":

> A point or pointed part projecting backward from a main point, as of a fishhook or arrowhead

Answer (score 0):

vertical:the right/left arm of arrowhead?
horizontal:lower/upper arm?

Answer (score -2):

The R package ggplot2 uses the term "arrow head" and that makes sense to me too in ordinary BrE.

Comment: Ummm... it makes sense that one of the lines which forms an arrow head is called the arrow head?

Comment: Well, it makes almost as much sense as the fact that a ‘‘day’’ is divided into two parts, one of which is ‘‘day’’.

Comment: @Scott You make a fair point but if I was trying to differentiate I'd probably say something like daytime and nighttime. Similarly I want a way to differentiate the edges of an arrowhead from the collective arrowhead.

Comment: So, you wouldn’t refer to the summer solstice and the winter solstice as “the longest day of the year” and “the shortest day of the year”?    :-)    ⁠